# Variable for loops with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Would like to do the following by recursion so that I can vary the number of 'for' loops:

```
n = 5
out = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        for k in range(j,n):
            out.append([i,j,k])
```

To return

```
out =   [[0 0 0]
         [0 0 1]
         [0 0 2]
         [0 0 3]
         [0 0 4]
         [0 1 1]
         [0 1 2]
         [0 1 3]
         [0 1 4]
         [0 2 2]
         [0 2 3]
         [0 2 4]
         [0 3 3]
         [0 3 4]
         [0 4 4]
         [1 1 1]
         [1 1 2]
         [1 1 3]
         [1 1 4]
         [1 2 2]...]
```

e.g.

```
def Recurse(n, p):
  # where p is the number of for loops
  some magic recursion 
  return out
```

I've had a look at some of the other recursion questions, but struggling to get to the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using recursion, use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which is equivalent to nested for loops in a generator expression:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
>>> list(itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

**edit:** Didn't realize that this isn't actually a Cartesian product since the inner loops use the outer variable to start the range, here is one possibility but it is not as efficient as it could be because it generates extra values and needs to check that each value is valid:

```
def nested_loops(n, num_loops):
    prod = itertools.product(range(n), repeat=num_loops)
    for item in prod:
        if all(item[i] <= item[i+1] for i in range(num_loops-1)):
            yield item

>>> list(nested_loops(3, 2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
>>> list(nested_loops(3, 3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)]
```

Comment: The OP's desired output isn't the Cartesian product, though -- there's no (1,0,0).  Check the range arguments.

Comment: @DSM - Right you are!  Didn't notice that on first read through, I'll start working on an edit.

Comment: @JoranBeasley XD not homework. trying to create a matrix of variables for least squares approximation, where the number of for loops sets the order (quadratic, cubic, etc.). the output is an index for the linear matrix. This probably doesnt make much sense, which is why I left it out of the Q

Comment: In Python 2.7+. you can just write `itertools.combinations_with_replacment(range(n), w)`, I think.

Comment: @DSM I think you are right, add it as an answer for a +1, that is much better than my hacked together solution!

Answer (score 2):

@DSM has a better answer (but in the comments)

However here is a simple recursive solution, in case anyone is struggling to work it out

```
def f(n, p, start=0):
    if p==0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(start, n):
            for j in f(n, p-1, i):
                yield [i]+j
```