# Generalize nested "for" loops with recursion

Tags: arrays, recursion, vbscript

I have a simple routine with hard-coded nested for-loops that returns every unique two-value combination in an arbitrary array.  That is, given the input array {A, B, C}, the output is:

```
A B
A C
B C
```

Here is the code (VBScript, out of necessity):

```
sub subset2(a)
    for i = 0 to ubound(a) - 1
        for j = i + 1 to ubound(a)
             msgbox(a(i) & " " & a(j))
        next
    next
end sub
```

I would like to generalize this to produce every unique n-value combination from the input array.  That is, given the input array {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, I'd like to be able to specify that I want every two-value combination, three-value combination, etc.

This smacks of recursion, and I think that John La Rooy might have posted an answer that I could use ([Variable for loops with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848165/variable-for-loops-with-recursion)), but I can't map that to VBScript (or C, or JavaScript, or anything else I'm familiar with) and get it to work.

While undoubtedly the entirety of the Internet already knows the answer and need not read this far down, here is the routine that returns unique three-value combinations:

```
sub subset3unique(a)
    for i = 0 to ubound(a) - 2
        for j = i + 1 to ubound(a) - 1
            for k = j + 1 to ubound(a)
                msgbox(a(i) & " " & a(j) & " " & a(k)
            next
        next
    next
end sub
```

And its associated output, given input of {A, B, C, D}:

```
A B C
A B D
A C D
B C D
```

Any takers?

Comment: So do you want the answer in Three value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely lends itself to recursion.  Here's one way to do it:

```
Sub SubsetUnique(n, a)
  ForEach n, 0, UBound(a) - (n - 1), "", a
End Sub

Sub ForEach(Level, Min, Max, StartString, a)
  For i = Min To Max
    If Level = 1 Then
      MsgBox StartString & " " & a(i)
    Else
      ForEach Level - 1, i + 1, UBound(a) - (Level - 2), StartString & " " & a(i), a
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For a nonrecursive approach, make an array where the index is the position in the output, and the value is the current position in the input that you've reached for that output column.  Initialize it to 1, 2, 3, etc.  Do a loop in which you increment the last position in that array which isn't maxed out, and then reset all following positions to equal the successors of the incremented one.  Read out the input value found at array[n] for each output column n.

Answer (score 0):

I have no VBScript skill, but something like this should do the trick:

```
sub subset(n, a, prefix)
    if n = 0 then
        msgbox(prefix)
    else
        for i = 0 to ubound(a) - 1
            subset(n - 1, a, prefix && " " && a(i))
        next
    endif
end sub
```

You invoke it with an empty prefix.